# Tensorflow or Theano: Is there a special option for evaluation to use less memory?

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, theano, recurrent-neural-network

I am exploring some of the deep learning libraries including Chainer, Torch, TensorFlow, and Theano.

Formerly I was a user of Chainer, and I found that Theano or Tensorflow has a great flexibility and seems to have a nice future potential.

However, what keeps me from moving to Theano or Tensorflow is the memory issue. Is there an option to make Theano or Tensorflow do not keep computation history? In Chainer it can be done by setting `volatile` flag, so that I can evaluate large data with less memory because it does not keep unnecessary data (which are only necessary when calculating gradients).

I am primarily working with RNNs, and the typical approach to training RNNs is to use truncated BPTT. However I found that it is useful and has slightly more accurate to feed the full sequence to the network when I want just forward computations, not backpropagation.

I tried to find this option from documentions of both frameworks, but I couldn't find. Is there a reason that this feature cannot be implemented?

Comment: Do you have a good example of a model where you'd like to save memory? This would help us evaluate how well we're doing, and work on memory reduction approaches.

Comment: By turning off computation history, do you mean setting trace level to 0 here (https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/protobuf/config.proto#L188)?

Comment: Sorry for checking your comments so late. @PeteWarden: As stated in the content, just a simple RNN sequence prediction model would be an example. Say the length for truncated BPTT be 64, and there exist the sequence of length 1000 in the dataset. I found that it is more accurate if a single length-1000 sequence is fed to the model than several chunks of length-64 sequences are fed. However in Theano or Tensorflow, every computation accumulates a computation history and the intermediate results must be kept in the memory; which makes it hard to predict multiple sequences in large batch size.

Comment: If the computation history isn't accumulated, then it can reuse memory blocks containing the results of previous computations for the expense of losing the ability for backpropagation. In Chainer it is done by setting a volatile flag, which indicates that "it does not keep computation history, and the backpropagation cannot go further this."

Comment: @YaoZhang: Unfortunately I haven't found what NO_TRACE means. I am wondering whether "trace" mean "trace when the exception occurred", or "trace of previous computations"... I will keep seeing that.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I think this is an implementation detail/feature for RNN; not sure if Tensorflow supports it. The tracing ability I was mentioning is unrelated and is for debugging purpose.